# Changing the appearance of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to change the appearance of a fragment (set a different View) during its operation or is it possible only in the onCreateView () method?

Comment: Are you talking about the `setContentView`  method?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.
Not to create chaos in the management of widgets. It is better to use child fragments or show/hide necessary widgets. The answer found [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513804/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-layout-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-mainactivity/513812#513812).

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do it this way:

1. Return some placeholder view (e.g. FrameLayout) in your onCreateView() and keep reference to it.
2. Then, you can add/remove other views from your placeholder view, when you need to do so.

However, I think it is not how Fragments are supposed to be used. (changing its views rapidly during runtime)